# How to make a custom select box with filter using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, select

I am having a problem with jQuery Mobile. I want to make a custom select box with search option on the top like in the ul of jQuery mobile. I have made a custom select box using jQuery mobile but cannot add the search bar on it. I want exactly the thing like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/sEMyT/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link class="jsbin" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="https://github.com/downloads/aliok/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile_selectmenu_filter_01.js"></script>
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">

  <h2>Select menu options filtering</h2>

            <p>The mobile browsers are limited and sometimes it is annoying to scroll a long list. For this kind of selects, you can use <code>data-filter</code> attribute alongside with <code>data-force-dialog</code> and <code>data-native</code> attributes to have a select menu with search bar filtering its options.</p>


            <a href="#" onclick="$('#select-choice-12').selectmenu('refresh', true); return false;">Refresh the selectmenu (forcerebuild) with clearing the filter value</a>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="select-choice-12" class="select">Your state:</label>
                        <select name="select-choice-12" id="select-choice-12" data-native-menu="false" data-force-dialog="true" data-native-menu="false" data-filter="true">
                            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                            <option value="CA">California</option>
                            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                            <option value="NY">New York</option>
                            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
        You can see the source code at <a href="https://github.com/aliok/jquery-mobile/commits/selectmenu-forceDialog/">https://github.com/aliok/jquery-mobile/commits/selectmenu-forceDialog/</a>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Developed by <a href="http://twitter.com/aliok_tr">Ali Ok - @aliok_tr</a> 

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But the problem with that it is customized with a very old version of jQuery Mobile and I am using the latest version.

Comment: You could create something new. Bind a click event on the select element, and when it's clicked prevent default behavior and open a dialog with a listview with search filter. When an element of the listview is clicked, change the value of the select element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just follow the example on the JQM demo pages [Filter inside Custom Select](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/selectmenu-custom-filter/)

Comment: @frequent Do you know if this is possible with a multiple select?

Answer (score 2):

I hope you can Use **Select2** or **Chosen**

Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes. It supports searching, remote data sets, and infinite scrolling of results.

For more details and Demo : check [**Select2**](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)  or Try [**Chosen**](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Its implemented in our some projects and its works fine.

Answer (score 2):

check out this in the jquery mobile site:

[selectmenu-custom-filter](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/selectmenu-custom-filter/)

this is the original jquery mobile solution

Answer (score 2):

this link its the best https://github.com/studiosedition/JQM-Custom-Search-Filtering-Example i tested

recommended by http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1929169

other example for custom filter

http://jsfiddle.net/dondavidml/ekbo4uy5/

```
$("ul").listview('option', 'filterCallback', function (text, searchValue) {
console.log(" searchValue " + searchValue.toUpperCase() + " text " + text.substring(0, searchValue.length).toUpperCase());
if (searchValue.toUpperCase() == (text.substring(0, searchValue.length).toUpperCase())) {
    return false;
}
return true; });
```

be careful, the order matters in the imports like this

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/search-filter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

:D