# Jquery mobile stuck on loading while trying to follow demo

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add a searchable select control to my Jquery mobile powered web application.The only Stack Overflow question I could find on the topic is this one

[Jquery Mobile: How to Make Custom Select Box with filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094930/jquery-mobile-how-to-make-custom-select-box-with-filter)

It recommends following the demo located here

http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/selectmenu-custom-filter/

HTML

```
<form>
<select id="filter-menu" data-native-menu="false">
    <option value="SFO">San Francisco</option>
    <option value="LAX">Los Angeles</option>
    <option value="YVR">Vancouver</option>
    <option value="YYZ">Toronto</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$.mobile.document
// The custom selectmenu plugin generates an ID for the listview by suffixing the ID of the
// native widget with "-menu". Upon creation of the listview widget we want to place an
// input field before the list to be used for a filter.
.on( "listviewcreate", "#filter-menu-menu,#title-filter-menu-menu", function( event ) {
    var input,
        list = $( event.target ),
        form = list.jqmData( "filter-form" );
    // We store the generated form in a variable attached to the popup so we avoid creating a
    // second form/input field when the listview is destroyed/rebuilt during a refresh.
    if ( !form ) {
        input = $( "<input data-type='search'></input>" );
        form = $( "<form></form>" ).append( input );
        input.textinput();
        list
            .before( form )
            .jqmData( "filter-form", form ) ;
        form.jqmData( "listview", list );
    }
    // Instantiate a filterable widget on the newly created listview and indicate that the
    // generated input form element is to be used for the filtering.
    list.filterable({
        input: input,
        children: "> li:not(:jqmData(placeholder='true'))"
    });
})
// The custom select list may show up as either a popup or a dialog, depending on how much
// vertical room there is on the screen. If it shows up as a dialog, then the form containing
// the filter input field must be transferred to the dialog so that the user can continue to
// use it for filtering list items.
.on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, data ) {
    var listview, form,
        id = data.toPage && data.toPage.attr( "id" );
    if ( !( id === "filter-menu-dialog" || id === "title-filter-menu-dialog" ) ) {
        return;
    }
    listview = data.toPage.find( "ul" );
    form = listview.jqmData( "filter-form" );
    // Attach a reference to the listview as a data item to the dialog, because during the
    // pagecontainerhide handler below the selectmenu widget will already have returned the
    // listview to the popup, so we won't be able to find it inside the dialog with a selector.
    data.toPage.jqmData( "listview", listview );
    // Place the form before the listview in the dialog.
    listview.before( form );
})
// After the dialog is closed, the form containing the filter input is returned to the popup.
.on( "pagecontainerhide", function( event, data ) {
    var listview, form,
        id = data.toPage && data.toPage.attr( "id" );
    if ( !( id === "filter-menu-dialog" || id === "title-filter-menu-dialog" ) ) {
        return;
    }
    listview = data.toPage.jqmData( "listview" ),
    form = listview.jqmData( "filter-form" );
    // Put the form back in the popup. It goes ahead of the listview.
    listview.before( form );
});
```

CSS

```
.ui-selectmenu.ui-popup .ui-input-search {
  margin-left: .5em;
  margin-right: .5em;
}
.ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-content {
  padding-top: 0;
}
.ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-selectmenu-list {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.ui-selectmenu.ui-popup .ui-selectmenu-list li.ui-first-child .ui-btn {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-header {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

However even when exactly copying the code from this demo into a new test project, the page will not load and gets stuck on the spinning loader animation.

What am I missing here? Thank you.

### Edit

**Console Errors**
Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3), not all, only screen and (min-resolution: 200dpi) 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loader' of undefined jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi Yes, I will post them in the question

Comment: Use jQM 1.4.x not 1.3.x. Edit: [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/cuuSQ/).

Comment: @Omar Thanks, switching to 1.4 made my demo work. However now I am faced with the problem of making this work in the Grails project I am working on, which is a big huge project that already uses jQM 1.1.0.5 and im not even sure if I should touch that or exactly how to..(I am not the original creator of this app but I am the main developer now)

Comment: Well, using latest version of jQM is recommended. However, it depends on your application; new features have been added, old features have been removed.